# WCF Dataservice - modify object before returning results?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I am using WCF data services and I have a few fields/properties that I want to "blank out" (set value to empty string or null) before sending back to client.

For example: User table has password column which I do not want to pass the value to the client.  This is one example, there are other such columns in the app that the value should be excluded for security/privacy reasons.

Sorry for such a basic question, I'm new to WCF dataservices and have not found any promising leads yet.  I've tried QueryInterceptors but no luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, just make a new query that got only the data you want your client to see - this should be easier don't you think?

Comment: @Carsten I've tried that before but the security is placed on the client to exclude the sensitive fields.  I need the security on the server side to keep tampering down to a minimum.  Dies that make sense?  Am I missing something you were trying to say?

Comment: No I meant your server. I don't used Dataservice before (don't like it too much) but as I get it you create a EF-model or whatever and expose this right? Then just use a model that does not include the sensitive fields.

Comment: @John, finally what did you come up with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO this is out of scope of WCF Data Services. WCF Data Services are meant to take your entity model and expose it as is based on access rules. If your entity exposes some properties and that entity is exposed its properties are simply public. It is for simple CRUD scenarios or read-only scenarios.

`QueryInterceptor` will not help you because it can be used for data driven authorization - it means that `QueryInterceptor` can add some additional condition to filter records which current user is not permitted to see = it will filter out whole records but it will not modify filtered result.

There is no hook to null fields because that is a bad approach. If you don't want expose some fields they should not be part of exposed entity at all. You can create second read-only entity exposing only public fields by using [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) in your EDMX file. Next you need to modify access rules in your `DataServiceConfiguration`. You must remove access rule to initial `User` entity set and add read access rules to that new entity set.

If you need to control access rules per user you have to use some kind of [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728284.aspx) in your service and you must handle this in `InitializeService` method (unless `DataServiceConfiguration` is available elsewhere). Something like:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    var context = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
    if (context != null && context.PrimaryIdentity != null)
    {
        var userName = context.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
        if (SomeMethodToValidateUserPermissions(userName)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Users", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        }
    }

    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("TrimmedUsers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
}
```

By going more deep into WCF there can be other approaches to restrict access to some resources but this one is simplest.

Comment: "IMO this is out of scope of WCF Data Services. WCF Data Services are meant to take your entity model and expose it as is based on access rules." - means I cannot even do simple modification to data like DateTime formatting?