# WCF Data Service - Restrict visibility and logging queries

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-data-services, odata

I have two questions related to WCF Data Service:

1. is there a way to restrict the entities visible to a user according to her privileges ?  For instance user in role super-user should be able to query the full 'Contact' entity but user with less privileges would only be able to see specific properties of the 'Contact' entity.
2. whenever a user runs a query on the service, I would like this to be logged in a database for audit purpose. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

1) There is the concept of interceptors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx

But I think they won't satisfy you in your case:
With change interceptors you can handle requests which try to change a specific entity. This could help you to avoid users without certain privileges to add/change/delete contact entities. With QueryInterceptors you can handle GET-Requests. But they don't allow you to restrict certain properties of your contact entity.

You are not the first with such requirements -> [WCF Dataservice - modify object before returning results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377119/wcf-dataservice-modify-object-before-returning-results/7377758#7377758)

Maybe you could use a combination of a (custom) ServiceOperation and a View to handle this.

2) Yes, you can do this for instance by handling the ProcessingRequest-Event:

```
public class YourService : DataService<Entities>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The logger.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly LogWriter logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="YourService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public YourService()
    {
        this.logger = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();
        this.ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += this.ProcessingPipelineProcessingRequest;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnProcessingRequest
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">source</param>
    /// <param name="e">event args</param>
    public void ProcessingPipelineProcessingRequest(object sender, DataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs e)
    {
        this.logger.Write(new LogEntry { Message = "SOP ProcessingPipelineProcessingRequest: Unauthorized Access", Severity = TraceEventType.Warning })
    }
}
```

You can find all those ProcessingPipeline-Events here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceprocessingpipeline(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I've been using QueryInterceptors for filtering records and that works well but like you said, it's useless for filtering out properties. Wht do you mean by 'using a combination of a ServiceOperation and a View' ?  I'll look into the ProcessingRequest event.

Comment: Also, I have come across this article. I think it's a good compromise. I could have a 'full entity ' exposed to super users and a 'light' entity exposed to everyone.  What do you think ?http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/15/pre-filtering-and-shaping-odata-feeds-using-wcf-data-services-and-the-entity-framework-part-2.aspx

Comment: Hi! I meant that you can use a view for the user with less privileges. I don't know if you need that but the problem that occurs is that you can't insert any entites by using a view. That's why you could use a service operation in order to create the entity on the server side by using all the properties of the view as a parameter. Actually this may not the best or "prettiest" approach, but I personally disagree in having 1:1 relationships on the database only because WCF Data Services suck in terms of this requirement.